# Esperar função ser executada Kotlin | Android

Tags: android, mobile, kotlin

Eu tenho o seguinte codigo abaixo, quando eu chamo a função `getAllCharacters()` ele da o return antes do state ser definido.
Como eu posso fazer com que a função espere o state ser definido para depois retornarn ?

```
class FinalSpaceRepository {
    fun getAllCharacters() : ApiState{
        var retrofit = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance("https://finalspaceapi.com/api/v0/")
        val endpoint = retrofit.create(FinalSpaceApi::class.java)

         var state:ApiState = LoadingApiState()

        endpoint.getAllCharacters().enqueue(object : Callback<List<CharacterModel>> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<CharacterModel>>,
                response: Response<List<CharacterModel>>,
            ) {
                var list:List<CharacterModel> = mutableListOf()
                response.body().let {
                    list = it!!
                }
               state = SuccessApiState(list)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<CharacterModel>>, t: Throwable) {
               state = FailureApiState()
            }

        })

        return state

    }
}
```